# Micosoft Flow - process that is valid and working, sometimes get stuck for hours

Tags: microsoft-flow

Description: 
    While running my Flows, a process that is valid and working, sometimes get stuck for hours at a running status for no reason.
    After a few hours, it either suddenly finishes or i have to go into that task executions and cancel it. 
        What I need to understand:
    1. Can it be caused due to a specific problem ?
    2. Is there a specific problematic functionality?
    3. Is there a chance that my message is sent time after time once in that state?
    4. Is there any limitation to the amount of messages sent in an hour that will hold the rest of the messages in a queue for the next execution interval?
    5. In case there is an amount limitation, how can i change it ?